# After installing nodejs version 20.3.1 still --> TypeError: First parameter has member 'readable' that is not a ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, polyfills, astrojs

sorry to bother you with my tiny problem.
After reading threw the previous questions about the same error and installing nodejs and npm to the latest versions, the error is still showing up. And I dont know what to do to get rid of it.

This is what I get, when running dev:

```
PS C:\Users\maxim\maxim> npm run dev

> maxim@0.0.1 dev
> astro dev

   astro  v2.7.2 started in 182ms

  ┃ Local    http://localhost:3000/
  ┃ Network  use --host to expose

C:\Users\maxim\maxim\node_modules\web-streams-polyfill\dist\polyfill.js:362
            throw new TypeError(context + " is not a ReadableStream.");
                  ^

TypeError: First parameter has member 'readable' that is not a ReadableStream.
    at assertReadableStream (C:\Users\maxim\maxim\node_modules\web-streams-polyfill\dist\polyfill.js:362:19)
    at convertReadableWritablePair (C:\Users\maxim\maxim\node_modules\web-streams-polyfill\dist\polyfill.js:3524:9)
    at ReadableStream.pipeThrough (C:\Users\maxim\maxim\node_modules\web-streams-polyfill\dist\polyfill.js:3608:29)
    at fetchFinale (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11082:56)
    at mainFetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10974:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Node.js v20.3.1
PS C:\Users\maxim\maxim>
```

Please, can anyone help me figure out what I did wrong?
I am currently working on a simple static webpage with a few pics and a contact form. So nothing special really...

I am more than thankful for any kind of ideas! :-)

I tried:

- installing nodejs and npm to the newest versions as it has been mentioned in similar questions and answers in stack overflow conversations